# Как ограничить по времени доступ к разделу сайта? django

Tags: django

Проект на Django.

Нужно к одному из разделов сайта, например *"Связь с администрацией"* или *"Оформление покупки"* ограничить доступ по времени, например с 00:00 до 06:00 утра. **Как это сделать???**

В голову приходят много вариантов - ограничить на views, ограничить на forms или же вообще ограничить только на template *(что скорее всего не лучший вариант)*.
Буду благодарен любой помощи и советам.

**Вопрос: как осуществить ограничение по времени *(например с 00:00 до 06:00 утра)* на раздел сайта?** Как лучше всего сделать подобное ограничение - На views? На forms? На Template?

За примеры кода буду благодарен вдвойне.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил вопрос самостоятельно, но с подсказкой [anme](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/13225/anme).

Напишу решение, может кому-то пригодится, так как подобных вопросов по джанго нет.

Создал отдельный шаблон .html с уведомлением о том, что данный раздел закрыт от и до, по времени.

Реализацию сделал во *views*:

Сначала получил текущее время, и выбрал только - часы.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
hour_now = now.hour
```

Далее во *views* реализовал проверку:

```
if 23 < hour_now < 6:
```

После данной проверки уже идёт вся основная логика работы раздела.

В *else* просто подставил шаблон с уведомлением о том, что раздел закрыт.

Надеюсь ответ кому-то будет полезен.

Answer (score 1):

Я пишу не на Django, но логика была бы такой: провряется текущее время в контроллере и исходя из этого решается, какой шаблон показать - запрашиваемый или с уведомлением о том, что раздел закрыт до такого-то времени.

Я бы еще добавил появляющееся предупреждение на страницу, о том, что страница скоро перестанет быть доступной и подумал бы о том, как обрабатывать приходящие от пользователей данные, сохранять их в базе несмотря на время или в хранилище браузера, если это вообще необходимо. Ну и о часовых поясах не забудьте.